# getting 'ArticleSitemap' object has no attribute 'get_urls' error when creating sitemap in django

Tags: python, django, sitemap

follow the description on django official document and standard setup for a sitemap but got the following error:

AttributeError at /sitemap.xml/
'ArticleSitemap' object has no attribute 'get_urls'

there is my urls:

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from . import views
from .sitemaps import StaticViewSitemap, ArticleSitemap, ArticleCategorySitemap

sitemaps = {'static': StaticViewSitemap,
            'article': ArticleSitemap,
            'article-category': ArticleCategorySitemap}

urlpatterns = [
   path('sitemap.xml/', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
]
```

there is my sitemaps.py:

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from django.shortcuts import reverse

from iman_articles.models import Article, Category


class StaticViewSitemap(Sitemap):
    def items(self):
        return ['home']
    
    def location(self, item):
        return reverse(item)

class ArticleCategorySitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = 'never'
    priority = 0.5
    
    def items(self):
        return Category.objects.all()

    


class ArticleSitemap():
    changefreq = 'monthly'
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return Article.objects.filter(active=True)

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.edited_at
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ArticleSitemap` should inherit from `Sitemap`, so:

```
#                       ↓ inherit
class ArticleSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = 'monthly'
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return Article.objects.filter(active=True)

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.edited_at
```

Comment: thanks, it works in local server but at host with debug=False it shows empty page                 http://imanrezaei.ir/sitemap.xml/

Comment: @irectonic.com: If I run this with `curl`, I get the data. For example `<loc>http://www.imanrezaei.ir/articles/sitemap.xml</loc>`. Likely something in the browser is not working. Note that your SSL certificate is not valid.

Comment: its the error                                                                                                                            XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://imanrezaei.ir/sitemap.xml/
Line Number 8, Column 12: sitemap.xml:8:12
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.imanrezaei.ir/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Comment: @irectonic.com: yes, most browsers will block AJAX requests to another domain: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#How_CORS_works

Comment: must set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://imanrezaei.ir at host?